# Android unfortunately has stopped App

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

code

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="fill"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="contentDescription" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="You Have Clicked 0 Times!"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:background="@style/AppTheme"
        android:src="@drawable/cherry" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Im doing a tamago/click app just to learn some functions
please help and tell me if i did something wrong in here.
Im new coding and makin android app so im not sure why this happens it worked before

Comment: could you please post your logcat and read this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212969/how-to-ask-correctly-for-android-problems/212970#212970

Comment: We rather need your java code and Logcat than your layout xml.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277281/failed-to-install-hello-apk-on-device-emulator